# Fitting Website To Screen Size

Tags: html, css

so I have been working on a website. Now I am working on making it fit all screen sizes, and I have a problem. Here is a example:

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 1366px) {
    #wrapper {
        width: 1400px;
        height: 750px;
        position: absolute;
    }
}
```

Now the above will display the screen size as 1400 pixels if the screen size is at least 1366. Yet if the screen size is 1400 pixels, and your screen only happens to be 1366 pixels you are going to have to scroll side to side. That is my issue, but I have a idea on how to solve this. I would like to center the 1366 pixels of content in the middle, and then if the screen size is bigger the left over pixels will be equally divided on the sides. Example:

> My screen size is 1500 pixels. Minimum screen size is 1200 pixel. Then
>   150 pixels will be added to each side of the 1200 pixel content (sense
>   there are 300 pixels left over).

Now on the sides where there are no content (because the pixels are bigger) I want there to be a background color. So simply how would I achieve this? If this does not make sense please just post a comment and I will try to make this more clear. Thank You :)

**EDIT:**
People are asking, why can you not just do width:100%. That would not work because if you shrink the screen size it messes up everything.

Comment: why can't you use `width: 100%` ?

Comment: did you try `screen.width`and `screen.height`.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO. You're right, your question is over complicated for the question you're asking. What you're essentially asking is 'how to center a div'.

```
#wrapper {
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

For the background, you can do:

```
body {
   background-color:#000;
}
```

Edit for your first issue: `#wrapper {overflow:hidden}` to remove the scroll bars, although this would only really be applicable for images, otherwise you could go for 100% on the width. Depending on your design you might benefit from reading up on responsive frameworks.

Comment: Hello, you answer is helpful. Yet I still have a question :) If your amount of pixels are bigger then the amount of content, how do I center the content on your screen?

Comment: @user3448743 as per my edit which you may not have seen, I did not see your first issue. If you are using a background color, using 100% on the width would be better than a fixed pixel width.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**CSS**

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 1366px) {
     #wrapper {
          width: 100%;
          height: 750px;
          position: absolute;
     }
}
```

Comment: Note: no need of `margin: 0 auto` as the width of the container is `100%`. :)

Comment: Hello, yours would not work. That is what I was originally trying, yet if you use 100% it will mess up stuff when the width gets smaller.

Comment: @user3448743 give `width: 100%` in media queries. that will definitely work in your case.

Comment: @user3448743: did you tried it outside or inside media queries dear ??

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are asking for. I think this is it:

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 1366px) {
    #wrapper {
        width: 1400px;
        height: 750px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
    }
}
```

I think @SajadLfc answered your question but still not sure because he got downvote :/

Answer (score 0):

To get screen width and height

use this,

```
width = screen.width;
height = screen.height;
```

and

```
width = window.innerwidth;
height = window.innerheight;
```

Hope this helps.